# I am getting this error : "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead."

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4, codable

Here is my JSON format:

```
[
  {
    "date": "17-06-2015",
    "title": "Night Shift no 58",
    "venue": "Sugarfactory",
    "city": "Amsterdam",
    "country": "NL",
    "fb_url":"https://www.facebook.com/events/00000",
    "ticket_url":"https://shop.eventtickets.com/00000"
  },  
  {
    "date": "24-06-2015",
    "title": "Night Shift no 59",
    "venue": "Sugarfactory",
    "city": "Amsterdam",
    "country": "NL",
    "fb_url":"https://www.facebook.com/events/00000",
    "ticket_url":"https://shop.eventtickets.com/00000"
  }  
]
```

Here is my implementation:

```
struct Result: Codable {
    let Object: [Event]
}

struct Event: Codable {
    let  date:  String?
    let  title:  String?
    let  venue: String?
    let  city:  String?
    let country: String?
    let fbUrl: String?
    let ticketUrl: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String,CodingKey {
        case  date = "date"
        case title = "title"
        case  venue = "venue"
        case city = "city"
        case country = "country"
        case fbUrl = "fb_url"
        case ticketUrl = "ticket_url"
    }
}
```

Here is my JSON parsing code:

```
 if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "events", withExtension: "json") {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)

            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let jsonData = try decoder.decode(Result.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            print("error:\(error)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I meant jsonData line

Comment: You don't need the `Result` structure because you don't have the root object as `Dictionary`. Instead you have your JSON as `Array` format. Change the decoding line as `try decoder.decode([Event].self, from: data)` and your code will compile.